# Emacs - file path in variable to register

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm quite new to Emacs and I've encountered with a problem. I want to set a register to a variable, my code is here:

```
(defvar org-file-location "")
(defvar system-name-as-string (prin1-to-string system-name))

(cond ((string-match "WIN-WORK" system-name-as-string)
           (setq org-file-location "~/../My Documents/Google Drive/Org"))
          )

(set-register ?o '(file . org-file-location))
```

But when I try jump to register by a key sequence **C-X r j o**, I get a error: **find-file-noselect: Wrong type argument: stringp, org-file-location**.
Does anyone know, there the problem is ?
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the register to a value that includes the symbol `org-file-location`, but you want its value as a variable.

Try this:

```
(set-register ?o (cons 'file org-file-location))
```

or, using the backquote syntax to interpolate values:

```
(set-register ?o `(file . ,org-file-location))
```